# Django Foreign Key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have a places model and ratings model:

```
class Descriptions(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    street1=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    street2=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    zip=models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True)
    description=models.TextField()
    areas_related=models.TextField()
    add_area=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    federal=models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
    lat=models.TextField(blank=True)
    long=models.TextField(blank=True)
    creator=models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' %(self.name,self.website,self.street1,
    self.street2,self.city,self.state,self.zip,self.description,self.add_area, self.federal, self.lat, self.long, self.creator)
```

for the places. Then I have:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    rating=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    place=models.ForeignKey(Descriptions)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' %(self.rating, self.place)
```

In my views I use annotate to get the average of ratings:

```
 relevant=Descriptions.objects.annotate(Avg('rating__rating'))
```

Now, can I add to this queryset so that I will also be able to access which users have given a rating? Or do I have to create a separate queryset? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can always access the User who has given the rating.

Example,

```
for desc in Descriptions.objects.annotate(Avg('rating__rating')):
    for rating in desc.rating_set.all():
           print rating.user
```